# Create own Custom Field for Joomla 5

Tags: development, custom-field, custom

I am looking at how to create my own custom field using a self implemented form field in Joomla 5.

I started my extension in the same way as the core extensions (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/5.0-dev/plugins/fields/) and put my own field in the `/src/Field` directory of my Extension.

I have also tried to add the path via

```
FormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_PLUGINS . '/' . $this->_type . '/' . $this->_name . '/src/Field');
```

But my form field does not seem to be found. I think this, because the `type` is always set to the default `text`.

I now wanted to do further research. But I can't find the place where the form field is set. I only find a `getField()` [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/b17a2ed3253b6a7b0c7c538b269fff27075b5f78/libraries/src/Event/CustomFields/AbstractPrepareFieldEvent.php#L91). But no `setField()`.

Where do I have to look?

Is there perhaps an example of a custom field that uses a self-created form field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [attempts so far](https://codeberg.org/astrid/j4examplecode/src/branch/t42/src/plugins/fields/agosmsmarker) have ended in code that does not load the form field either.

I have created a question on Github. See: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/discussions/42246

Here I found the solution in

> For namespaced field you need to use `FormHelper::addFieldPrefix()` to
> register your namespace in the form, instead of
> `FormHelper::addFieldPath()`. Example
> `FormHelper::addFieldPrefix('Foo\Bar')` for field `Foo\Bar\BeerField`